# How to mix Netbeans Designed JFrame Form and Scala

Tags: java, swing, scala, netbeans

A long time ago (almost 5 Years) I used to code in Java. Now I'm trying to do some Scala code on Netbeans. What I'm trying to do it's quite simple to do on plain Java/Swing/Netbeans (and even more easier to do on WinForms/C#): Design a form, with a JTextField, a JButton (which will work as a Submit button, that will feed a List with the String on JTextField)and a JTable (which will show all strings within the aforementioned List).

Well, here comes the Scala part: all the "business rule" (take the String from the JTextField, add string to List and refresh the JTable, and moreover, saving this list onto a text file) must be in Scala.

I already have Netbeans with Scala plugin, scalac and all necessary stuff (I think)

After some trying, I think I can't mix Scala code inside an "ActionPerformed" listener from a JButton (just for an example).

How could I accomplish that? Could you point me some resources on how to get that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't use scala-swing?

Comment: @nachokk thank you for answering. Is there a way to stick scala-swing and the Netbeans designer together?

Comment: No idea, more than what google provide i can't give you